# weird faces when shrinkwrap

Tags: shrinkwrap

i'm getting weird shaped faces when trying to retopology my high poly model into lower poly . I'm using shrinkwrap and weird faces happen on the ear. I tried subdividing but it didnt work. What do you guys think it is?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe try putting the shrinkwrap modifier above the subdivision surface modifier in the stack and add a picture of the result?

Comment: It loses all of the details from my high poly mesh when i put my subdivision below shrinkwrap but thanks :) I used projection mode instead of nearest surface point it worked for me